facebook marketing API Unable to create adset with targeting
need some help
i'm trying to create an adset with cities in the targeting object but i'm getting an error
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_data": "{\"blame_field\":\"targeting\"}",
        "error_subcode": 1487756,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Locations can't be used",
        "error_user_msg": "Some of your locations overlap. Try removing a location.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AApf6HmHZneXVFLD1U8BK-D"
    }
}

steps to reproduce
1- create a campaign
curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/$API_VERSION/$ACCOUNT_ID/campaigns -F 'name=My Campaign' \
   -F 'objective=OUTCOME_AWARENESS'\
   -F 'status=PAUSED' \
-F 'special_ad_categories=[]'\
   -F "access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN"

then, create an adset for this campaign
curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/$MY_META_ACCOUNT_ID/adsets \
  -F 'name=My Ad Set' \
  -F 'campaign_id=6680088172618' \
  -F 'daily_budget=1000' \
  -F 'targeting={"geo_locations":{"countries":["US"],"cities":[{"key":2427178}]}}' \
  -F "access_token=$MY_META_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F "billing_event=IMPRESSIONS"

